# What are the names of the children of Gabrielle Delacour?

Tags: harry-potter

Who are the children of Gabrielle Delacour? What are their names?

Comment: Are you looking for canon sources?

Comment: This is based off of fan-fiction (more specifically [Scopatore](https://harrypotterfanon.fandom.com/wiki/Gabrielle_Delacour_(Scopatore))), right?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please can you [edit] in if you're after canon sources (the books jkr wrote) or a specific fanfiction. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is no current canon information on the descendants of Gabrielle Delacour. In currently canon works, the latest we hear of her is in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, at the wedding of Bill and Fleur. She was eleven years old at the time.

> "And, of course, you ’ave met my leetle daughter, Gabrielle!" said Monsieur Delacour. Gabrielle was Fleur in miniature; eleven years old, with waist-length hair of pure, silvery blonde, she gave Mrs. Weasley a dazzling smile and hugged her, then threw Harry a glowing look, batting her eyelashes. Ginny cleared her throat loudly.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 6: "The Ghoul in Pajamas"</sub>

We do not have any information on Gabrielle after that point.

Comment: Fleur was only 11 when she married Bill?!? Scandalous! :)

Comment: @Alarion Fleur wasn't 11 when she got married it was Gabrielle,Fleur's little sister who was 11

Comment: @AnnabelleSmillie I know. I was just making a joke about how the "she" in the last sentence before the quote is a little ambiguous.